# Yii2 Rest Custom actions with OPTIONS request

Tags: rest, api, yii2

I am working on api up to now it has only been tested in Postman so cors wasnt an issue. However now developing the front end and when it comes to custom Yii actions they are failing the preflight request. I solved this by adding these lines to url-manager config:

```
 [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => ['v1/call-rates'],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'OPTIONS' => 'options',
            'GET all-resellers' => 'all-resellers',
            'POST updatefromcsv' => 'updatefromcsv',
            'OPTIONS all-resellers' => 'options',
            'OPTIONS updatefromcsv' => 'options',
            // other end points....
        ],
```

So every custom action has to have a corresponding OPTIONS pattern. I have seen on a similar question that it is possible to apply the OPTIONS pattern to all custom actions in one line like so:

```
 [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => [
            'v1/call-rates',
            // rest of controllers... 
        ],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'OPTIONS <action:\w+>' => 'options',
        ],
    ],
```

However that is not working. I have also tried with a token like this:

```
  [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => [
            'v1/call-rates'
        ],
        'tokens' => [
            '{action}' => '<action:\\w+>',
        ],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'OPTIONS {action}' => 'options',
        ],
    ],
```

But again no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you extending `yii\rest\ActiveController` or `yii\rest\Controller`? and is there any authentication implemented? if yes did you add exception for `OPTIONS` verbs like [shown in docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#cors)? also what do you mean by not working? what is the status code you get when performing an `OPTIONS` request (can you test it please via either browser or postman) is it 401, 405, 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the following in to urlmanager config:

```
 [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => [
            'v1/call-rates',
            'v1/call-recordings',
        ],
        'tokens' => [
            '{action}' => '<action:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+>',
        ],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'OPTIONS {action}' => 'options',
            'OPTIONS' => 'options'
        ],
    ],
```

Because my custom actions were named like:

```
public function actionGetResellers
```

The Url would be `get-resellers` so the pattern was incorrect as it didn't accept `-`'s. So now what whatever controller I add it will add OPTIONS pattern for every custom action

Answer (score 0):

I use Regular Expression  `<action:\w+-\w+>`. Here is the solution:

```
[
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', //
        'controller' => 'v1/content/my',
        'pluralize' => false,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'OPTIONS <action:\w+-\w+>' => 'options',
            'GET foot-print' => 'foot-print', 
            'GET my-courses' => 'my-courses',
        ]
```